# How to Display Cross Sell Products on Products Details Page Under tab Section?

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, magento2.2

I am trying to add cross sell products under product details page tab section, and using below code but not working in magento 2.3.5

```
<block class="Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Crosssell" template="Magento_Catalog::product/list/items.phtml" name="crosssellstab" as="crossselltab" group="detailed_info" >
            <arguments>
                <argument translate="true" name="title" xsi:type="string">Cross sell</argument>
                <argument name="type" xsi:type="string">crosssell</argument>
            </arguments>
        </block>
```

Please help, how to i can fix this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution :-

```
 <referenceBlock name="product.info.details">
        <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Related" name="product.info.related" template="Magento_Catalog::product/list/items.phtml" group="detailed_info">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="type" xsi:type="string">crosssell</argument>
                <argument translate="true" name="title" xsi:type="string">Crosssell Products</argument>
                <argument name="sort_order" xsi:type="string">40</argument>
            </arguments>                
        </block>
    </referenceBlock>
```

Hope this help you

Thanks ...